# Encoding of Latin 2 signs in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to enable my C++ program to accept both 
signs from CP852(Latin 2) in form of text written in the console, as well as loaded up from a simple text file.
I cannot figure out what is the default encoding since either way gives me different ANSI code. 
I've set the CP to Central European (DOS) 852 
in Advanced Save Options.

1) casting with `(int)ł` gave me the number **136**

2) assigning to a variable `unsigned char sign = 'ł'` and printing it on the screen with `cout` gave me the number **136**

3) using "Add watch" control to the variable containing ł, it shows the number **179**

4) while loading from a text file, **179** again, using this simple code

```
int x;

FILE* plik;
plik= fopen("Text.txt", "r"); // It contains 2 signs, "oł"
while ((x = fgetc(plik)) != EOF)
{
    cout << (char)x;
}
fclose(plik);
```

Output: "o|"

My main question is, why does it handle the same sign (or am i wrong?) "ł" once as **136** and other time as **179**? How to deal with this problem? This way i cannot print and accept a sign with comparison, since their codes are different, even if what is in the file is exactly the same as in the console window.

Comment: Unless you're trying to support a pre-90's codebase, why not use Unicode?

Comment: I'm currently writing a Huffman method text compression program, that's why my first thought was to use encoding fitting one byte. ANSI seemed to be the obvious choice, as my needs include only standard alphabet + specific Latin2 signs.

Comment: use UTF-8. It's the obvious choice. ANSI will become a mess if you don't understand what charset is

Comment: @Mr_Max: As you're writing a compression program, **it really** doesn't matter. Huffman coding assigns a variable-length code to `ł` based on its frequency. The source encoding really doesn't matter, as long as your compressor knows how to get the proper input tokens (i.e. with UTF-8, you need to consider whether you want to compress bytes or characters)

Answer (score 0):

First check your text.txt file with a hex-editor, it should contain bytes 0x6F and 0x88 (111 and 136). When you read this file from your C++ program, output the values as int, not as char, to determine the correct values. Outputting it as a char requires an output codepage to be used consistent with what you expect. See the Properties, Options tab, Current Code page in the command prompt that runs your C++ app. It this is not CP852 it will not show the characters as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a different version of *fopen*:

```
FILE* plik= NULL;
int err= _tfopen_s(&plik, _T("Text.txt"), _T("rt"));

if(err != 0 || plik == NULL)
{
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    return 1;
}
```

See also documentation:

- [fgetc, fgetwc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1.aspx)
- [_fgetchar, _fgetwchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/410hkeyx.aspx)